# Can .cnt file be converted to spectrogram images in matlab? if yes then how to do it?

Tags: matlab

I have an EEG signal with .cnt and .fdt files. I have to obtain images to use it as input to a cnn. Is it possible to convert the file to images? Someone please help me with this. If possible then specify how to do it.

Comment: Hey, please provide a more specific question and sample code for someone to help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should download EEG tollbox such as EEGlab or [FieldTrip](http://www.fieldtriptoolbox.org/download/). I prefer fieldtrip because it is script based while EEGlab is more about GUI. Here you can see fieldtrip's function [ft_read_header](http://www.fieldtriptoolbox.org/reference/ft_read_header/) that can deal with your files, and here is a basic script to [read cnt](https://github.com/yuval-harpaz/ft_BIU/blob/d787d5cca5b5c5f8f9df13f3e02fff816d63d0e9/matlab/files/readCNT.m) files with fieldtrip functions